# R unnest_tokens elements from list

Tags: r, token, tidytext, unnest

I have this:

```
library(tidytext)
list_chars <- list("you and I", "he or she", "we and they")
list_chars_as_tibble <- lapply(list_chars, tibble)
list_chars_by_word <- lapply(list_chars_as_tibble, unnest_tokens)
```

got this:

```
Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.
```

want to get this:

```
[[1]]
1 you
2 and
3 I

[[2]]
1 he
2 or
3 she

[[3]]
1 we
2 and
3 they
```

please help, I believe I have tried everything, but evidently no, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unnest_tokens()` needs to be told which column to parse, so you need to name the character column in your tibbles:

```
library(tidytext)
library(tibble)

list_chars_as_tibble <- lapply(list_chars, function(x) tibble(txt = x))
lapply(list_chars_as_tibble, unnest_tokens, word, txt)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  word 
  <chr>
1 you  
2 and  
3 i    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  word 
  <chr>
1 he   
2 or   
3 she  

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  word 
  <chr>
1 we   
2 and  
3 they
```

Comment: thanks H 1, it works like a charm, where can I learn things like that? Where can I close this question?

Comment: Thanks... I don't see the "tick" where to close this post... all I have are three squares next to the answer with "active", "oldest", "votes", I click votes but nothing